# Loading a pretrained model in PyTorch, error:object not callable

Tags: python, pytorch, fast-ai

I am trying to load the `Efficientnet-b6` weights using `PyTorch` and `Fastai`:

```
PATH = '../input/EffnetB6/efficientnet_b6.pth'
model = torch.load(PATH)
```

The above model is part of another model:

```
class EARUnet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, pretrained_net, out_ch=1):
        super(EARUnet, self).__init__()
        # print("EfficientUnet_git_b6_res")
        self.pretrained_net = pretrained_net
        .
        .
```

When I run:

```
net = EARUnet(model,1)
learn.fit_flat_cos(10)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object is not callable
```

What is the model's format requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the restrained context, I suspect that the problem resides in `model`, probably containing an `OrderedDict` of the EfficientNet model state dict, while the EARUnet expects the EfficientNet `nn.Module`.

You should instead, try something like:

```py
eff_net = EfficientNetB6()
eff_net_state_dict = torch.load(PATH)
eff_net.load_state_dict(eff_net_state_dict)

net = EARUnet(model, 1)
```

Have a look at this [page](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html) for more details.

Comment: I tried before what you suggested, but it didn't work. I suppose that the issue is about my EfficientNetB6 model, where I could download it?

Comment: The [timm](https://github.com/rwightman/pytorch-image-models#models) package contains lot of pretrained models for image recognition. Have a look at it!